# how to use coalesce in postgresql to replace null value with ""

Tags: postgresql

I need to use coalesce to replace null value with "" without any space in the 
  output.

```
coalesce(trim(phone,'',""))
```

Comment: You can read about coalesce documentation or few examples for the same.

Comment: `coalesce(trim(phone),'')`

Comment: Do you have any good link

Comment: The manual? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html

Comment: You have multiple errors in your query: `trim()` can only have 1 parameter,  while `coalesce()` can have multiple & the empty string is `''`. The `""` parameter will be resolved as a (column, or alias) identifier (an empty one, which i'm not sure if it's legal on its own or not).

Comment: Please explain what exactly you want. What is a NULL value inside a string?